# Internet Slow; but not for Proxy--Why?

Tags: proxy, internet-connection, fios

My internet connection has been flaky for the past 3 days (Verizon FIOS).

It's not the computer, because the connection has been poor for several devices in the house.

Strange, some sites (Google, Superuser, Facebook, Woot, Amazon, National Weather Service etc.) all load perfectly fast as usual.

Other sites (like Craigs List, Sports sites, Consumer Reports, Navy Atomic Clock etc.) won't load. But here's whats really odd: these sites that don't load, most load perfectly fine with a bit of delay when I go to them by a proxy website.

Why would the connection be fine for some sites, and not others, and then almost all work through proxy? The last time this happened, there were widespread DOS attacks.. I have not heard that is the case recently.

It's like my internet connection is doing the Maine "you can't get there from here" routine.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue and fixed it by disabling IPv6 on my computer.